# bison: store custom classes

Tags: c++, parsing, bison

I'm now learning Bison and writing a toy compiler with it. As I've found I can store different values using %union directive, but sadly %union doesn't support my own classes. How can I save them? Let's say I have one base class which is called `object_type`; this class has a couple of virtual functions and some inheritors like `bool_type`, `int_type`, etc.
I can create a pointer `object_type*` which can hold any type of subclass, but it can hold only one object; what if I have a condition e.g. `OBJECT AND OBJECT`? If I'll use union, I can just use `$1` and `$3` to get values; but I'd rather preferred to work with my own types which have functions which I need. Can be there a solution? Thanks in advance!

```
%{
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {
  int yylex(void);
  int yyparse(void);
  int yywrap() { return 1; }
} /* extern "C" */

void yyerror(const char *error) {
  cerr << error << endl;
} /* error handler */

%}

/*============================================================================*/
/* Create Bison union and stack */
/*============================================================================*/
%code requires {
#ifndef __TYPES_HPP_INCLUDED__
#define __TYPES_HPP_INCLUDED__
#include "types.hpp"
#endif
}

%union {
  object_type* pointer;
  none_type*   none_buffer;
  bool_type*   bool_buffer;
  int_type*    int_buffer;
  float_type*  float_buffer;
  bytes_type*  bytes_buffer;
} /* union */
```

g++ returns this error: `error: ‘bool_type’ does not name a type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hybrid solution and store a union that holds pointers to objects of multiple different types.  For example, if you have `int_type` and `bool_type` objects, you could create a union like this:

```
%union {
     int_type*  iType;
     bool_type* bType;
     /* ... */
}
```

That way, if you have a production like `OBJECT AND OBJECT`, you could have actions like

```
$$ = new bType($1->memberFunctionOnBool() && $3->memberFunctionOnBool());
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Compiler tells `bool_type does not name a type` if I try to add member `bool_type* bool_buffer` to union.

Comment: @ghostmansd- Did you include the header file in which `bool_type` was declared?

Comment: yes, of course; I also use these types in rules and they works, but if I try to add to union, g++ refuses to compile.

Comment: @ghostmansd- There is no fundamental reason that you wouldn't be able to use `bool_type*` in your union.  I suspect that your error is elsewhere.

Comment: I've now noticed that it doesn't works with C++ extended types like map or vector. In my source these types work and only in union not.

Comment: @ghostmansd: You need to `#include` the header file(s) that define these types inside a `%code requires {`...`}` block in the bison source file.

Comment: @ghostmansd: Assuming `"types.hpp"` defines `bool_type`, you need to `#include "types.hpp"` BEFORE `#include "parser.tab.h"` anywhere you have the latter.

Comment: @ghostmansd: Also, I can guarentee you that g++ does NOT give the error as you describe -- it will ALWAYS provide (at least) a file name and line number as well.  If its in a header file it will also provide a path for how it got to that header.

Comment: Ba, I've already found the reason. I need to add some parts of code (see original question).

Comment: Thank you very much for solving this question!